# Split audio into many files

Tags: audio, software, editing

I have an mp3 recording that spans many hours. It is just one big file. I would love to split it into dozens or hundreds of individual snippets.

I actually already some most of the time-stamps where I'd need a split, and also have some names for the individual parts. Other times I don't yet know. I feel I can't just search for silence, as this is a live recording and probably is never silent. The question is then, how do I do this with as little effort as possible?

I would like to give this list of time-stamps and headlines to a software, then receive the individual mp3 files some hours later. Do you know any software like this?

My first idea was using Audacity. This has the added bonus of visually displaying the audio curve, so I can fine-adjust where exactly to split. However, the actual splitting and saving seems quite bothersome.

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach with Audacity: [Splitting a recording into separate tracks](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/splitting_a_recording_into_separate_tracks.html).

See also my original answer to the question [How to transfer records from cassettes to the computer?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5736/how-to-transfer-records-from-cassettes-to-the-computer/5737#5737) for other options.

Answer (score 0):

I have used "mp3DirectCut" to do some basic splitting of a CD image (big mp3 with no pauses) but i did it manually since it had no cue sheet with it. I know it handles cue sheets but I have never test it.

Also I've used cue sheets with these :

[CUETools](http://www.cuetools.net) & [MedievalCueSplitter](http://www.medieval.it/cuesplitter-pc/menu-id-71.html)

Both of them did an excellent job, but I did not write the cue sheet my self. You'll have to come up with that.